# what's the best image input type for tesseract?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I'm using tesseract on a project and want to know the best image input type for tesseract to give the best output. Is Binary&TIFF the best input or there's something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had excellent results using TIFF in the past for a similar task. At the time I did some [pre-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10233208/176769) using OpenCV and exported the result to a TIFF file that later was sent to tesseract. It was pretty good.

Answer (score 5):

I've found TIFF to give far superior results to jpg, as well as being the best against all other types.

The original Tesseract programme would only work with TIFF files, leading me to believe it would be the most appropriate

Answer (score 0):

The advantages to using .tif is that (1) scantailor outputs .tif files and (2) it is possible to use tiffcp to merge individual .tif's into a single multi-page file that can be fed to tesseract.  The difficulty is that if you have tesseract output a .pdf, then you have no control over the type of .pdf created.  Using `pdfimages -list`, I find it outputting a combination of .ccitt and .jpeg at the same dpi as the input.  Then, attempting to use imagemagic to convert it to lower dpi or an other compression gives poor results.

The alternative I found is to first use imagemagic to convert all .tif's to .png.  Then feed the .png's to tesseract one-by-one, producing a .pdf for each .png.  In that case, the .pdf's now contains raster images.  Those can then be combined and re-encoded with imagemagic.

The only downside I can see here is that *if* tesseract is learning as it OCR's the document (I don't know that it is, but it may be), then we would want to give it the whole document at once rather than one page at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using the above mentioned tif

```
pdfimage -tiff in.pdf page ; 
convert page-*.tif document.tif ; 
tesseract document.tif document --psm 1 --oem 1 pdf
```

Is significantly (~20%) slower than using PNG:

```
pdfimages -png in.pdf page ; 
for png in *.png; do 
   tesseract... ; 
done ;  
pdfunite page*.pdf document.pdf
```

**but** the resulting pdf's are much bigger.

```
Measured on MAC M1 (10CPU) - 3456x4704 400dpi pages 6 ocr's in parallel

    TIF: Time: 1466 Pages: 2520 Docs: 100 Sec/Page: 0.581746
    PNG: Time: 2703 Pages: 5620 Docs: 180 Sec/Page: 0.480961 
 TIFFCP: Time: 1957 Pages: 4768 Docs: 269 Sec/Page: 0.410445
```

( Update: replacing convert with tiffcp makes a difference - I reject my previous comment  )

Comment: Not sure, mutool is part of muPDF, is it not? It seems fairly huge and a complex package. Anyone has performance figures for it?

Comment: Ok, a quick check, using mutool on an ancient AMD 8 core: gives for my specific file 7 seconds using mutool, 0.7 seconds using pdfimage -tiff, and 6 seconds using pdfimages -png  (~ 20 pages  3296 x 4677  400dpi b/w).
Maybe it really boils down, look at your images and try ...

Comment: In the end, for scan's, the problem child is something like: ``` convert -density 300 -trim -quality 70 -flatten -sharpen 0x1.0 -deskew 40% -set option:deskew:auto-crop 10 ``` which is the bottleneck by a magnitude,