# Does Tesseract neglect any nontext area in a scanned document?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract, text-extraction

I'm using Tesseract but I don't know whether it neglects any nontext area and targets text only. Do I have to remove any nontext area as a preprocessing step for better output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tesseract has a pretty good algorithm to detect text, but it will eventually give false-positive matches.

Ideally, you would pre-process the image before submitting it to tesseract. Some time ago I engaged in a similar task, so I suggest you take a look at the following material:

- [OpenCV C++/Obj-C: Detecting a sheet of paper / Square Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667818/opencv-c-obj-c-detecting-a-sheet-of-paper-square-detection/8863060#8863060)
- [Executing cv::warpPerspective for a fake deskewing on a set of cv::Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838487/executing-cvwarpperspective-for-a-fake-deskewing-on-a-set-of-cvpoint)
- [Rotate cv::Mat using cv::warpAffine offsets destination image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813376/rotate-cvmat-using-cvwarpaffine-offsets-destination-image)
- [Affine Transform, Simple Rotation and Scaling or something else entirely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800905/affine-transform-simple-rotation-and-scaling-or-something-else-entirely)